# Dúvida sobre Código MYSQL + Delphi

Tags: mysql, delphi

Segue o código:

```
  DModuleGrid.qtudo.close;
  DModuleGrid.qtudo.sql.clear;
  DModuleGrid.qtudo.sql.add('select numcupom from tabc460 where cderr <:mc');
  DModuleGrid.qtudo.parambyname('mc').asinteger := 0;
  DModuleGrid.qtudo.open;

  if DModuleGrid.qtudo.recordcount > 0 then
  begin
    DModuleGrid.qres2.close;
    DModuleGrid.qres2.sql.clear;
    DModuleGrid.qres2.sql.add('delete from tdcupant where impcaixa = '+
      QuotedStr(impcaixa)+' and dtcompra between :dini and :dfim');
    DModuleGrid.qres2.parambyname('dini').asdate := date1;
    DModuleGrid.qres2.parambyname('dfim').asdate := date2;
    DModuleGrid.qres2.execsql;

    DModuleGrid.qtudo.close;
    DModuleGrid.qtudo.sql.clear;
    DModuleGrid.qtudo.sql.add('insert into tdcupant (select * from tabc460 '+
      'where dtcompra between :dini and :dfim) ');
    DModuleGrid.qtudo.parambyname('dini').asdate := date1;
    DModuleGrid.qtudo.parambyname('dfim').asdate := date2;
    DModuleGrid.qtudo.execsql;
  end;
```

Então, minha dúvida, é se o meu `delete`, vai deletar apenas aqueles que ele achou no `Recordcount`, ou vai deletar tudo que ele encontrar...
Alguém poderia me esclarecer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> delete from tdcupant where impcaixa = '+
>        QuotedStr(impcaixa)+' and dtcompra between :dini and :dfim

Ele irá deletar todos os registros que:

- Tiverem o **impcaixa** igual ao informado
- Cujo **dtCompra** seja maior ou igual ao parametro **dini** e menor ou igual ao **dfim**

Não tendo nenhuma relação com o `Recordcount`

Para deletar os registros encontrados na `DModuleGrid.qtudo` faça:

```
while not DModuleGrid.qtudo.IsEmpty do
  DModuleGrid.qtudo.Delete;
```

Comment: Deu certo amigo, agora entendi direitinho. Obrigado.